# Is it necessary to have all devices in same network to receive the push notification using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Service

Tags: google-app-engine, networking, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ip-address

1. I have implemented Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) Push notification using Google App Engine (Java).

   2. I have created WiFi hot spot on my device to access internet for laptop (Operating system: Ubuntu 12.04).
   3. Google App Engine as HTTP server.
   4. I am following [official docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)
   5. Command to run server :

      ant -Dsdk.dir=/home/myUserName/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18 runserver
      -Dserver.host=My_Network_IP Buildfile: gcm-demo-appengine/build.xml

**Please note My_Network_IP is taken from system settings--> network -->wireless-->IP Address**

6. The demo-app for push notification is taken from
   https://github.com/google/gcm
7. I have changed required things like API key,sender_id,server_url etc.
8. Now when I send the push notification from server my device receives the message. In this scenario both my laptop and device are in same network (laptop is using internet of device).
9. When I run the same client code on other device which uses its own mobile data (internet), the app is not getting registered hence I am not able to send the push notification.
10. When I connect this device to WiFi of my earlier device and opens up app it is getting successfully registered.
11. I am wondering is it necessary to have all my users under same network which I am using for my server? or I am doing something wrong?

Please clarify my doubt.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your server code on your local machine, only devices connected to the same WiFi network can contact your server code to pass it their Registration IDs. This has nothing to do with GCM.

If you are going to release your app, you'll need to deploy your server code to some web server, which will allow any Android device to connect to it and send to it the Registration ID (regardless of the type of internet connection the device uses).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my doubt Eran. Can you please suggest some best web server?

Comment: @Programmer it really depends on your language of choice GCM has an API for the most popular laguages. But App engine is pretty good and you can deploy it on the cloud in minutes with no charge (until you get a heavy user load).

Comment: @jirungaray "you can deploy it on the cloud in minutes with no charge" I dont know how to do this? can you give me steps please? I am using app engine as a server but running on localhost. And I already have large user base near about 14000.

Comment: well. it's a bit much to go over a comment, but App engine is designed to be used on the Google cloud infraestructure, the local server is just  testing tool (quite limited i might add) please make sure to read the basics on the [app engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) i pointed you to Java since i see you are using ant but there are more languages supported.

Comment: I got an app which is on play store right now. I want to implement push notification using gcm in it. I started with a demo app using Google App Engine as a server. I am able to send test push notification using my local machine IP like I said in my question. Now  I wants to integrate the same in my app so that all my users will get notified. How to achieve this using Google App Engine?